# get null values with Where and left join

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

Let's have this query

```
   select music,fav from MUSIC music

        left join  Favorite_Music fav on fav.id_music  = music.id_music  

        where fav.id_user= 22 or fav.id_user is NULL
```

my Table `Music` :

```
  id_music  |  ....

     1      |  
     ...    |   
     100    |
```

my Table `Favorite_Music` :

```
id_fav  |  id_music  |  id_user

 1      |   15        |  22  
 2      |   20        |  22  
 3      |   40        |  30
```

I want to retrieve all `MUSIC` and for some stuff i want to mark the favorite musics of my `user 22`.

But when i execute the query above the `music` `40` is not included !!

So i want to get all the `music` and get null value for `Favorite_Music` which are not of my 22 user.

Comment: The `id_user` has a value of `30` in the row where you're expecting to retrieve `40` from the `id_music` column?

Comment: yes like i show in my question i want to retrieve this row too

Comment: In your `Favourite_Music` table why would you expect the third row to be returned when `or fav.id_user is NULL` forms part of your `WHERE` clause? In that instance the value isn't null, it's `30`
Unless I'm woefully misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i want to get null value when `fav.id_user `is different from 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply filters to outer joined tables in the join clause, not the where clause.  Like this:

```
select music,fav 
from MUSIC music
left join  Favorite_Music fav on fav.id_music  = music.id_music  
and (fav.id_user= 22 or fav.id_user is NULL )
```

When you filter in the where clause, which seems like an obvious thing to do, your outer join becomes an implicit inner join.

Comment: like @GordonLinoff answer it work even without `fav.id_user is NULL` condition.

Answer (score 1):

This is the query that I think you want:

```
select music, (case when fav.id_user is not null then 'No' else 'Yes' end) as IsFav22
from MUSIC music left join
     Favorite_Music fav
     on fav.id_music = music.id_music and fav.id_user = 22;
```